# Integrated graphics only or integrated + dedicated

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, adobe-photoshop, intel-graphics, integrated-graphics, autocad

Consider the following setup:

1. A machine with a processor (plus integrated graphics) and
2. another machine with the same processor and integrated graphics
   but aditionally a dedicated graphics card which is worse than the
   inegrated one.

My question is now if its better to get the machine with the additional dedicated GPU or not?

I'm aware that the integrated graphics will use my RAM.

- Will the inegrated graphics "function" of the CPU and the CPU share some bandwidth with each other or are they independent?
- Will somehow the graphics functin of the CPU interfere with the "CPU function", meaning will I get a performance loss due to heavy GPU and CPU load at the same time even tho I have enough RAM (16GB) for the tasks I want to perform?
- Will I get a benefit from the additional dedicated GPU?  I cannot obviously use the integrated GPU and the dedicated one at once for photo editing for example and since the integrated is better I dont see the sense of the dedicated in it or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: Do you have a particular laptop in mind? Because AFAIK machine #2 just doesn't make sense. If it's not about some specific device, why are you asking this question? Is there a practical problem that led you to this question?

Comment: Well yes I have a particular laptop in mind I already mentioned it before in a question but it got closed for "hardware shopping recommendations" so I tried to ask the question very neutral without mentioning any specifc devices now. Machine #2 in fact exists thats why I am asking... In fact its a combination of the  i7-1165G7 (11 Gen, Intel Iris Xe G7 80EUs) and the GeForce Mx 330. I checked the benchmarks and the integrated Iris graphics is appearently much better so I dont see the sense of the dedicated graphics in it. Therefore Im asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between on board and discrete graphics](https://superuser.com/questions/1057581/what-is-the-difference-between-on-board-and-discrete-graphics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will the integrated graphics "function" of the CPU and the GPU share
> some bandwidth with each other or are they independent?

They are independent - only one of them will work at a time.

> Will somehow the graphics function of the CPU interfere with the "CPU function", meaning will I get a performance loss due to heavy GPU
> and CPU load at the same time even though I have enough RAM (16GB) for
> the tasks I want to perform?

RAM will not be a problem - however, you might experience an impact in CPU performance when using an integrated GPU. Take a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1533988/does-integrated-graphics-slow-down-cpu).

> Will I get a benefit from the additional dedicated GPU? I cannot
> obviously use the integrated GPU and the dedicated one at once for
> photo editing for example and since the integrated is better I dont
> see the sense of the dedicated in it or am I thinking wrong?

The combination of Intel Iris Xe G7 80EUs and GeForce MX330 is indeed a strange one, since Iris seems to be the better, faster option. It would make sense to go for MX350 for example - or maybe Nvidia GTX/RTX series (1xxx, 2xxx, 3xxx). If you're doing a lot of GPU-intensive work (Adobe Photoshop, AutoCAD), you should consider something like Nvidia GTX 1050ti for the dedicated card.

Comment: I know it’s a bit late but thx for answering! I understand the context much better now. Thank you for your help.